# How to get title of the page from URL in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to extract the title of page the url points to, and display it on my web page, in my react web app.

I've tried a few npm packages but no luck.

Comment: So, do I get it that you want to load another website from your website, and actively read out the title of that page? Also when that title might have been altered by javascript? Can you expand on what you have tried so far?

Comment: I just want to get the title of the webste or page without actually loading that url, I tried link-preview-js npm package but CORS gives a problem, I ve searched on google , no luck